# I'm having problems with img scaling within a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I'm trying to recreate this ui card that I made using bootstrap tabs/pills and columns and rows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThyeG.jpg

The only problem is when I add the link to the img and resize the card the image is deformed and doesn't scale properly. Do I have to add to the css or rescale the image? Thanks.

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">

<div class="box">

    <div class="maincontainer">

        <div class="thecard">

           <div class="row no-gutters" style="height:100%;">


           <div class="col-4 dedicated">
          <img src="assets/img/handshake.jpg" alt="handshake-meeting" style="background-size:cover;">
                </div>


                <div class="col-8 dedicated-back" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <div class="mt-auto price">
                  <h1 class="dedicated-heading">Dedicated internet nedir?</h1>

              <p class="dedicated-para">
                  <ul class="dedicated-para">
                      <li>-İndirme ve yükleme hızını siz seçin.</li>

                      <li>-Statik ip’niz olsun.</li>
                      <li>-AKN’niz ya da herhangi bir limitlendirmeniz olmasın.</li>
                      <li>-Kameralarınızı takılmadan istediğiniz gibi seyredin.</li>
                 <li>-Tüm şirketlerinizi birbirine bağlayın.</li>
                  <li>-Mesai dışında bile olsa kendinize özel müşteri temsilcisi ve teknik desteğe sahip olun.</li>
                   <li>-Hafta içi haftasonu demeden teknik destek alın.</li>
              <li>Yönlendirme ve VPN işlemlerini ücretsiz bir şekilde sabah 8:00 gece 23:00 saatleri arasında anında yaptırın</li>
                  </ul>
 </p>




                  <p class="dedicated-info">Fiyat İçin Lütfen Bilgi Alınız</p>

                  <p class="dedicated-info">05333203252</p>





                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>                



 </div>       

</div> 




 <div class="container container-print">
           <h6>1) Kurumsal müşterilerimizin kendilerine özel müşteri temsilcileri bulunmaktadır. Yapılan sözleşmeler doğrultusunda, yine kendilerine özel kurallar belirleyebilmektedirler.</h6>


          <h6>2)  Kurumsal Teknik Saha olarak, bireysellikten ayrılan hizmetimizde, her daim teknik servis imkanı sağlanmaktadır. herhangi bir teknik durumunda nöbetçi ekipler müdahale ederek destek sağlamaktadırlar.</h6>
    </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output? Also, Please use the code snippet.

Comment: The expected output is the one in the image. Have the image in a row of 4 columns, how do I use the snippet? Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: I don’t see any classes added to the img. My first guess is to add the class img-fluid.

Comment: @NezihDogruer, Edit your question and after the image icon, you will find the code icon https://prnt.sc/ofk7z2 and add your code according to it.